# Mysql Left Join Null Result

Tags: sql, mysql, null, left-join

I have this query

```
SELECT articles.*, 
       users.username AS `user` 
 FROM `articles` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON articles.user_id = users.id 
 ORDER BY articles.timestamp
```

Basically it returns the list of articles and the username that the article is associated to. Now if there is no entry in the users table for a particular user id, the `users` var is NULL. Is there anyway to make it that if its null it returns something like "User Not Found"? or would i have to do this using php?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT a.*, 
          COALESCE(u.username, 'User Not Found') AS `user` 
     FROM ARTICLES a
LEFT JOIN USERS u ON u.id = a.user_id
 ORDER BY articles.timestamp
```

Documentation:

- [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

The reason to choose COALESCE over IF or IFNULL is that COALESCE is ANSI standard, while the other methods are not reliably implemented over other databases.  I would use CASE before I'd look at IF because again - CASE is ANSI standard, making it easier to port the query to other databases.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
SELECT articles.*, IFNULL(users.username, 'User Not Found') AS `user`
FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `users` ON articles.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY articles.timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF()` where in Oracle you would have used decode.

So

```
SELECT articles.*, IF(users.username IS NULL, 'No user found', users.username) AS `user` 
FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `users` ON articles.user_id = users.id 
ORDER BY articles.timestamp
```

Should work.
Note: I dont have mysql handy, so did not test the query. But should work with minor modifications if it fails. Do not downvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT articles.*, 
       IFNULL(users.username,'User Not Found') AS `user` 
FROM `articles` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON articles.user_id = users.id 
ORDER BY articles.timestamp
```

Comment: Double quotes on User Not Found? ;)