# MySQL - No result when joining tables using a NULL value

Tags: mysql

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894075/mysql-left-join-null-result) but this is slightly different...

I have two tables that I want to join:

```
location
---------------------------
| id | city    | state_id |
---------------------------
| 1  | Denver  |        6 |
| 2  | Phoenix |        2 |
| 3  | Seattle |     NULL |
---------------------------

state
-------------------
| id | name       |
-------------------
| 1  | Alabama    |
| 2  | Alaska     |
| 3  | Arizona    |
| 4  | Arkansas   |
| 5  | California |
| 6  | Colorado   |
-------------------

SELECT
    location.id,
    location.city,
    state.name
FROM
    location
JOIN
    state ON state.id = location.state_id;
```

However, in the case where `location.state_id` happens to be `NULL` (perhaps the person inputting the data forgot to select a state), the query would not return a result, but that doesn't mean the location doesn't exist.

How do I get around this problem and somehow display all the locations, even though the `state_id` might be `NULL` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT
location.id,
location.city,
state.name
FROM
    location
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    state ON state.id = location.state_id;
```

Comment: Never used that one before. Thanks!