# Show static value if id has no value in other tables in joinning tables

Tags: mysql

I want to show static data using mysql if id has no value in another table. I've used Left Join in joining them and if the id from another table does not exist in the table joined it will not display a thing, so is it possible to display a value for that specific id with no equal values in the other table?..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894075/mysql-left-join-null-result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COALESCE(yourLeftJoinTable.yourLeftJoinField,0) to display 0 if the value is null i.e.

```
SELECT
  table1.*,
  COALESCE(table2.id,0) AS table2ID
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table2.t1_id = table1.id
```

The following assumes table1 has field (id INT PK), and table2 has fields (id INT PK, t1_id INT) where table2.t1_id links to table1.id